# isight/bluetooth/wifi cable replacement

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, webcam

I have to replace a wifi/bluetooth/isight cable on my mid-2009 MacBook Pro 13".  I have seen resources and vids that show how to essentially replace the cable up to the card and including the card but there is the other long end of the cable that feeds and connects too?  How do I replace this without causing damage.  Help!

Comment: Can we have some pictures? I'm confused as to what "other end" you're talking about. I'm assuming you've looked at [this iFixit guide?](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2009+AirPort+Card+Replacement/6019)